# How to create an Int32Array view that starts on an arbitrary byte of the buffer

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, typed

Given some ArrayBuffer like:

```
var data = new ArrayBuffer(64);
```

I want to be able to write 32bit integers at any position (not only 32bit aligned).

For example:

```
[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9] ... byte data
   [__________][__________] ... I want to create an Int32Array with 1 byte offset
```

Is that possible?

Unfortunately, the `byteOffset` attribute is read-only and if it's set when creating the view, it only accepts multiples of 4 (for int32s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to read various types of values from arbitrary offsets, [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataView) is more handy. It has no alignment requirements.